# how to load middlewares in laravel exception handler for 404 page

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have a Laravel 5.6 app and I want to be able to load middleware when notFoundHttpException happens.
I've created a middleware to load global variables that I need to load every page e.g. categories in mega menu and I want to show that mega menu in 404 page too.

but when not found happens (404 page ) the middleware data is not loaded. 
I appreciate any help

this is my middleware that loads data to my views

```
public function handle ( $request , Closure $next ) {
        $clients = \App\Client::all();
        \View::share('clients' , $clients );
        ...
        ...

    return $next($request);
    }
```

and this is the code i wrote in the Exceptions/Handler class to customize the error page

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return response()->view("errors.404",[] , 404);
            }
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to create a custom 404 error page, then just create a page on`resources\views\errors\404.blade.php`, no need to customize the middleware

Comment: i have created the custom page . the problem is to load the data from middleware. my middleware not runs when there is an exception and laravel loads 404 page . which is logical . but i need this middleware to load before laravel renders the page

Comment: You wanna look at [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) than using Middleware for global variable injections on blade.  Like mentioned above just create custom resources\views\errors\404.blade.php file and use view composer to share your data on all views. It is not middleware job to pass the data to blade file.

Comment: @AnujShrestha I saw view composers . It looks like that's the right way to do this .there is another issue here though. there are two sets of variables that i want to share in my view. some are for admin panel and some for client and know because they're in middleware i used middleware based on route. how can i accumplish that using view composer ?